# query to get the count of each ID across both the tables

Tags: mysql, sql

We have two tables - T1 and T2. Both have a VARCHAR column called ID in both the tables. Write a query to get the count of each ID across both the tables.
Table name T1: | T2:
Column name ID  | ID

```
Data in table 
A | B  
B | C                                
C | D
```

Expected output:

```
ID ---- A, 1       
        B, 2      
        C, 2    
        D, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use union all and then apply aggregation

```
select id, count(*)
from
(
select id from T1
union all
select id from T2
)A group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following SQL to get the required output.

```
SELECT Id, COUNT(*) as Id_Count FROM
(SELECT Id FROM test_table1
UNION ALL
SELECT Id FROM test_table2
) AS final_result GROUP BY Id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, count(id)
from 
(select id from t1 union all select id from t2) as temp
group by id;
```